# Show decimal value on TM-1638 8 digit 7 segment display

Tags: c, embedded

I am doing a program in C in which I have to read the value of the button in my TM-1638 and sent it to the 7-segment display. I got through the reading part now I am having problems to show the value in the display. 
I have converted the value to BCD with this code:

```
const uint8_t dec[] = {0x3f, 0x06, 0x5b, 0x4f, 0x66, 0x6d, 0x7d,0x07,0x7f,0x6f};
if(readbyte > 0)
{
    num <<= 4;
    num |= readbyte % 10;
    readbyte /= 10;
}

senddatabyte(0x0a, dec[num]);
senddatabyte(0x0c, dec[num]);
senddatabyte(0x0e, dec[num &0x0f]);
```

in which `senddatabyte` sends the value to the selected adress of the 7 segment display.
It works good when it have to display one digit number but it doesnt work when it displays tens and hundreds.

Comment: You *do* realise that `num` must be in the range `0..9` to index the array? If so, why do you multiply it by 16 (`num <<= 4`)? That has either no effect (when `num == 0`) or puts it out of range (when `num >= 1`).

Comment: is the problem senddatabyte or is the problem in your math?  if you call senddatabyte and hardcode a value for each digit instead of dec[num] can you get it to properly display the value.   alternatively if you take this code on the target or on some other platform and printf the bcd is it correct and does it meet the senddatabyte() input requirements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For larger numbers, you have to use a loop. Loop while the number is larger than or equal to 10. Take the number modulus 10 to get the least significant digit, which you can print on the display. Then divide the number by 10 and loop again. And then finally when the loop is done and what remains of the number is a digit smaller than 10, print that digit too.